# Surface doesn't show up – pgfplots 3D

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-3dplot

I'm trying to draw this surface with pgfplots package
[image: x^/25+y^2/9-z^2/100=-1]

but nothing shows up.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, colormap={cm}{color(0)=(blue) color(1)=(blue!90) color(3)=(blue!80) color(4)=(blue!70) color(5)=(blue!10)}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
axis line style = thick,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
ylabel style={left},
ymin=-10,
ymax=10,
xmin=-20,
xmax=20,
zmin=-20,
zmax=20,
unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
width=15cm
]
\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,shader=interp,opacity=0.7,
samples=71,samples y=41,domain y=-10:10,domain=-10:10]
({x^2/25},{x^2/9},{x^2/100-1});   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I do not see how this parametrization, which has one parameter, represents the two-dimensional surface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation you post can be solved for z, yielding

```
z^2=100+4*x^2+100*y^2/9
```

so one has to plot

```
z=-sqrt(100+4*x^2+100*y^2/9)
```

and

```
z=+sqrt(100+4*x^2+100*y^2/9)
```

with the result (I commented out `unit vector ratio=1 1 1` since it does not look too good)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, 
colormap={cm}{color(0)=(blue) color(1)=(blue!90) color(3)=(blue!80) color(4)=(blue!70) color(5)=(blue!10)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
axis line style = thick,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
ylabel style={left},
ymin=-10,
ymax=10,
xmin=-20,
xmax=20,
zmin=-20,
zmax=20,
%unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
width=15cm
]
\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,
shader=interp,opacity=0.7,
samples=71,samples y=41,domain=-10:10,domain y=-10:10]
{-sqrt(100+4*x*x+100*y*y/9)};   

\addplot3[surf,mesh/ordering=y varies,
shader=interp,opacity=0.7,
samples=71,samples y=41,domain=-10:10,domain y=-10:10]
{sqrt(100+4*x*x+100*y*y/9)};   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

One can switch to polar coordinates.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest, 
colormap={cm}{color(0)=(blue) color(1)=(blue!90) color(3)=(blue!80) color(4)=(blue!70) color(5)=(blue!10)}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
[
axis lines = center,
axis line style = thick,
xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$,
ylabel style={left},
ymin=-10,
ymax=10,
xmin=-20,
xmax=20,
zmin=-20,
zmax=20,
unit vector ratio=1 1 1,
xtick=\empty,
ytick=\empty,
ztick=\empty,
width=15cm
]
\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,
shader=interp,opacity=0.7,
samples=12,samples y=61,domain=0:2,domain y=0:360]
({x*cos(y)*5},{x*sin(y)*3},{-10*sqrt(1+x*x)});   

\addplot3[surf,z buffer=sort,
shader=interp,opacity=0.7,
samples=12,samples y=61,domain=0:2,domain y=0:360]
({x*cos(y)*5},{x*sin(y)*3},{10*sqrt(1+x*x)});   
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @antshar You posted a question in which you say that the plot does not show up. This answer is to explain why that happens. It would be great if you could refrain from attributing the answer as "ugly".

Comment: Is it possible to make edges look nice like wolframalpha does?
https://imgur.com/X0B3ZoK

Comment: @antshar Yes, it is.

Comment: Thank you! Now it is what I wanted.